# python remove phone numbers from string

Tags: python, regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
rgf34 | 9 | 2015-07-20 | hello this is my number 1234567890 
rgf35 | 10 | 2015-07-20 | my number : 123 - 456 -8888 can you check...
```

The columns are pipe separated and each new data is on a new line.

How can i go through just the third column to **remove** all ph numbers? (all phone numbers are 10 digits and i do not know if they have brackets or dashes.)

I know i can use awk to just get data in the third column first but am stumped on how to do the regex part:

This is the awk part:

```
awk -F "|" '{print $4}' myfile.txt
```

Expected output:

```
rgf34 | 9 | 2015-07-20 | hello this is my number 
rgf35 | 10 | 2015-07-20 | my number : can you check...
```

Comment: is that exactly what the data looks like with spaces between the `-` and the digit?

Comment: yes some have spaces between the `-` and some dont because this is free range text that users input.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: To have the same text file format just without the numbers.please see update

Comment: Would it be sufficient to delete everything after "this is my number"?

Comment: no because numbers can appear anywhere in the third column. I will update my example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put this in a.awk

```
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "|"
}
{
    sub(/[0-9].*[0-9]/, "", $4)
    print
}
```

and run

```
awk -f a.awk foo.txt
```

You will get your desired output.

If the input is

```
rgf34 | 9 | 2015-07-20 | hello this is my number 1234567890 
rgf35 | 10 | 2015-07-20 | my number : 123 - 456 -8888 can you check...
```

The output will be

```
rgf34 | 9 | 2015-07-20 | hello this is my number
rgf35 | 10 | 2015-07-20 | my number :  can you check...
```

Comment: if i additionally want to remove things like 14 digit numbers, can i run this again and just change 9 to 14?

Comment: Actually, the `[0-9]` means a digit character, so that regex deletes everything between the first and last digit. You don't need to change anything to remove 14 digit numbers, as the regex is not specific to any length.

Comment: oh, so as long as there is a digit string, regex will delete it

Comment: if i need to keep 2 digit numbers, how can i do it?

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: like this: `rgf34 | 9 | 2015-07-20 | hello this is my number 1234567890...my age is 21...bla bla` to this ` `rgf34 | 9 | 2015-07-20 | hello this is my number ...my age is ...bla bla`