# Remove phone numbers from string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551902/python-remove-phone-numbers-from-string) but this actually remove all numbers. I only want to remove numbers with this format:

```
###-###-####
(###) ###-####
1-###-###-####
```

from the end of a string.
I can use regex, get the last n characters of a string, strip using "-" as separator, etc. but is there an easier way I am missing?

Comment: I don't understand "*get the last n characters of a string, strip using "-" as separator, etc*". Can you provide a short program that does what you want, even inelegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove phone numbers from the end of a string, using a regular expression seems easy enough to me:

```
stuff = [
    'My number is 212-555-1212',
    'My number is 212-555-1212, also',
    'What about (212) 555-1212',
    'or even 1-212-555-1212',
]

import re

for line in stuff:
    result = re.sub(r'((1-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})|(\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}))$', '', line);
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
$ python x.py
My number is 
My number is 212-555-1212, also
What about 
or even
```

Note that it removed phone numbers in each format from the end of the string, yet preserved the phone number in the middle of the string.